# Multithreading in Apache POI Workbook

Tags: java, multithreading, excel, apache-poi

I want to write into HSSFWorkBook or XSSFWorkBook in Multhreading environment. Each thread will do the modification in same or different sheet.

```
try {
    String filePath="C:/Test.xlsx";
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
    workbook.write(fos);
    fos.close();
    fileInputStream.close();
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

While testing this code in LoadTest with MultiThreading in SOAPUI. I got the exception in line:

```
Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
```

The exception is as follows:

```
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]
```

Comment: It looks like a file format problem. I would test it with a single thread first.

Comment: just to remind: You should be very accurate when you open same file simultaniously! Extremelly whith modify operation!

Answer (score 13):

Be aware: Apache POI explicitly does not support multi-threading access to the same workbook-object! This is because there are structures that are handled on a workbook-level, e.g. Styles, Comments, ...

You will run into obscure errors and corrupted documents if you try to do this naively.

The only guarantee that it makes is that separate workbooks in different threads will work fine, i.e. there is no thread-unsafe global state kept anywhere.

The only way that should work would be to synchronize every access to the workbook via a synchronized block:

```
synchronized (workbook) {
    ... access the sheet and the contents
}
```

Read-only access might work, but again Apache POI does not make guarantees that concurrent read-access to the same workbook will work.

Update: There is now a corresponding [FAQ entry](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N101BC) stating this as well.

Answer (score 1):

You create a `XSSFWorkbook` by reading the file `C:/Test.xlsx` ; the constructor called is [`XSSFWorkbook(InputStream)`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#XSSFWorkbook(java.io.InputStream)), which constructs a `OPCPackage`. 
This `C:/Test.xlsx` file has to be valid, i.e. not corrupted, not empty.

If you want to create a *new* workbook, you should not read an empty file, but rather use the appropriate constructor.

Regarding multi-threading, I haven't tested it but there are constraints on what the different threads can do (e.g. one per `XSSheet`). Look at this [mail archive](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/poi-user/201109.mbox/%3C1314859350817-4757295.post@n5.nabble.com%3E).

Answer (score 1):

There is the solution... I create rows into an array... and I use the array in the threads, Tu debes evitar use create rows into a thread because this method is monitored by thread safe

Sorry, I dont speak english... I am trying too hard.

```
static int count=0;

  

    
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Products");
    sheet.createFreezePane(0, 1); // this will freeze first five rows
    
    int rowCount = 0;
    
    rowCount = getExcelTittle(sucsCompetencia,sucsProveedor, sucsPuntoVenta, sheet, rowCount);  


    // trucazo para multithread
    List<Row> r = new ArrayList<Row>();
    //List<Drawing> h = new ArrayList<Drawing>();
    
    //cell creation
    for ( int j = 0 ; j < ps.size() + 500 ; j++) {
        r.add(sheet.createRow(j));
        //h.add(sheet.createDrawingPatriarch());

    }
    // cells creation .. its a good idea do it 
    Map<String,Cell> cellMap = new HashMap<String,Cell>();
    for (int j = 0 ; j < r.size() ; j++) {
        for ( int  i = 0 ; i < 9 + sucsCompetencia.size() + sucsProveedor.size() + sucsPuntoVenta.size() ; i++) {
            cellMap.put( j + "-" + i, r.get(j).createCell(i));
        }


    }       
    
    Stream<Producto> arrStream = ps.parallelStream();
    arrStream.forEach(p->
                        {   
                            count++;
        int contadorPropio = count;
        
        if (contadorPropio % 1000 == 0)  log.info("* Procesando Generacion Excel " + contadorPropio + " de " + ps.size());
        
       // if (rowCount == 1000 ) break;
        

        
        int columnCount = 0;
        
        
        {
            //IMPORTANTEEEEEEEE
            Cell cell = cellMap.get(contadorPropio + "-" + columnCount++); 
            cell.setCellValue(p.getIdProducto());
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Inside the main thread create the workbook, workbook create the sheets and distribute the sheets to worker thread. main thread should wait until all the worker thread completes. main thread workbook the flush the data into stream. then stream into file.

If you want source code with example, send a mail to me. I will share ramesh.niwas@gmail.com

Comment: please refer my blog: https://rameshvanka.blogspot.com/2020/03/excel-with-multi-threaded-way.html